# SSH connect to a remote database server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a **Rake task** to stop a remote MySQL server like following:

```
   task :stop_mysql do

     #SSH connect to the remote db server first
     #how???

     #then, run the following command
     system 'sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop'
   end
```

As you see above, now the **database server** is **remote**, I know the **IP** address of the database server.

How can I programmatically make **ssh** connection to the database server and run the command in the rake task above to stop MySQL?

**P.S.** the ssh configuration has been done (I mean the keys). Do not need to worry SSH configurations. I only need to know how the ruby code should be to make the SSH connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ssh can execute a single command instead of opening a new shell. This way, you can use `system` to execute your command on the remote host.

Try

```
system 'ssh user@host sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop'
```

(It might require some escaping for the second arg)

Comment: The ssh command needs to be quoted. In the shell it would look like: ssh user@host 'sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop'.

Comment: Me neither. That's why I explicitely told it might need escaping instead of posting an incorrect escaping.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it into a simple function and it's really handy:

```
def run( cmd )
  system "ssh user@host '#{cmd}' "
end

run( 'echo "aha coolness" >> test.txt' )
run( 'ls *.txt' )
run( 'cat test.txt' )
```

echo's something into a file test.txt
runs ls remotely
cat's the file remotely.

For your use case
    run('sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop')

Have an identity file and .ssh/config setup and it doesn't require typing passwords...